# NullInjectorError: No provider for BsDropdownConfig

Tags: angular, dropdown, ngx-bootstrap

I want to use the ngx-bootstrap dropdown, so i've import the lib in the app.module

```
BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
```

and in my html, i want to try the example found in the documentation

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
        <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
          Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
            role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
          <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

And i got this error in the console :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BsDropdownDirective -> BsDropdownConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BsDropdownDirective -> BsDropdownConfig]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for BsDropdownConfig!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BsDropdownDirective -> BsDropdownConfig
```

i've tried to import the BsDropdownConfig but it not a module.

is there any think that i must import ?

Comment: Hi. Can you share the full app.module please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is no default config provided by the `BsDropdownModule`, which is odd, but you can manually provide one, either in the root module injector (in the `providers` array), or in the component's own injector using

```
providers: [{ provide: BsDropdownConfig, useValue: { autoClose: true } }]
```

Comment: That's the case, thank's, it works

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I need to add the below dependency that is required.

```
 "ngx-bootstrap":"", //mention version compatable with your angular version 
  "ngx-intl-tel-input": "",
  "intl-tel-input",
  "google-libphonenumber"
```

please add this dependency inside **package.json** file with corresponding version
run the command :
**npm install**
after that import the **NgxIntlTelInputModule** module

```
imports: [
    NgxIntlTelInputModule,
],
```

**And add the theme for ngx input in angular.json file**

```
//keep your existing theme dont remove that.
     "styles": [
                 "", 
                 "./node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css"
               ],
```

If you have not added **intlTelInput.css** theme the country dropdown will not work only text input field diplay.