# NullInjectionError:R3InjectorError(CalendarModule) [BsDropdownDirective] NullInjectorError : No Provider for BsDropdownDirective

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I am encountering a **NullInjectorError: No provider for BsDropdownDirective!** error on the console while loading a particular component in the angular application. The component is about a calendar displaying some events. It might be related to some incompatible version between angular and some third-party library I am using but I am not sure. I am attaching an image for your reference of the exact issue

[image]

Here is my calendar.component.html

```
<div id="content">
  <pageHeader [items]="['Court Reporting', 'Calendar']"></pageHeader>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="form">
        <fieldset>
          <!-- Calendar legend -->
          <ul class="calendarLegend">
            <li>
              <i class="request-new fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Request New</li>
            <li>
              <i class="in-progress fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>In Progress</li>
            <li>
              <i class="in-production fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>In Production</li>
            <li>
              <i class="billed fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>Billed</li>
            <li>
              <i class="shipped fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>Shipped</li>
            <li>
              <i class="request-cancelled fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Request Cancelled</li>
            <li>
              <i class="cancelled fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cancelled</li>
            <li>
              <i class="back-order fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>Back Order</li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Toolbar -->
          <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
              <div class="pull-left">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" (click)="prev()" style="height: 30px; padding-left: 5px;">
                  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Prev
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" (click)="next()" style="height: 30px; padding-left: 5px; margin-right: 10px;">
                  Next&nbsp;
                  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <monthSelector id="monthSelector" *ngIf="isMonthView | async" (onGotoMonth)="gotoMonth($event)" [selectedYear]="currentDate.year.value"
                [selectedMonth]="currentDate.monthStr | async" style="margin-left: 10px;">
              </monthSelector>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="font-size: 1.75em; padding: 0; text-align: center;">

              <div class="pull-left">
                {{title}}
              </div>
              <div class="pull-right">
                <a [routerLink]="url.jobSearch" role="button" class="btn btn-success">
                    Search Calendar &nbsp;
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
              <div class="pull-right">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button id="viewAsCalendar" aria-label="View as Calendar" class="btn btn-default btn-xs active" (click)="changeViewAs($event, 'calendar')" style="height: 30px; padding-left: 10px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button id="viewAsList" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" aria-label="View as List"  (click)="changeViewAs($event, 'list')" style="height: 30px; padding-left: 10px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Calendar View -->
          <calendarView *ngIf="isCalendar | async" [viewBy]="viewByStr" [store]="self" [onDataReady]="dataReadyEvent" (onDayClick)="dayClick($event)"
          (onUpdateCalendar)="updateCalendar()"></calendarView>
        </fieldset>
      </div>

      <br/>

      <!-- List View -->
      <calendarList *ngIf="isList | async" [store]="self" [onDataReady]="dataReadyEvent" (onUpdateCalendar)="updateCalendar()"></calendarList>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

calendar.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SmartadminModule } from 'app/shared/smartadmin.module';
import { SmartadminInputModule } from 'app/shared/forms/input/smartadmin-input.module';
import { ROUTING } from './calendar.routing';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/uslsCore/modules/`shared/shared.module';

import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { PopupModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-popup';
import { DialogModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

import { CalendarComponent } from './calendar.component';
import { CalendarViewComponent } from './calendar/calendarView.component';
import { CalendarListComponent } from './list/list.component';

import { ApiService } from 'app/uslsCore/api/api.service';
import { CourtReportingApi } from 'app/uslsCore/api/courtReporting.api';
import { CourtReportingService } from 'app/uslsCore/services/courtReporting.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SmartadminModule,
        SmartadminInputModule,
        // KendoUI
        DateInputsModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        PopupModule,
        DialogModule,
        GridModule,
        // USLS
        ROUTING,
        SharedModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        CalendarComponent,
        CalendarViewComponent,
        CalendarListComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        CalendarComponent,
        CalendarViewComponent,
        CalendarListComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ApiService,
        CourtReportingApi,
        CourtReportingService
    ]
})
export class CalendarModule { }
```

I get this error as soon as I go the calendar component so mabe its related to a kendo library thats internally using botstrap but I am not sure. I even tried searching about this error but did not find anything worth noting that could solve this issue.

Comment: if you're or internally using ngx-bootstrap, or check if module added in app module BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69674542/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-bsdropdownconfig

Comment: @PraveenSoni I saw this but it did not help me.